# Странная ошибка в Python: NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток. Почему Python говорит что функция "is not defined" ?

main.py:

```
class Parser:
    acc = 0.0
    rest = ''

    def parse(self, s):
        self.acc = 0.0
        self.rest = s

        parse_plusminus()

        return self.acc

    def parse_plusminus(self):
        cur = parse_num()

        while len(self.rest) > 0:
            if not (self.rest[0] == '+' or self.rest[0] == '-'):
                break

            sign = self.rest[0]
            next_num = parse_num(self.rest[1:])

            if sign == '+':
                self.acc += cur + next_num
            else:
                self.acc += cur - next_num

    def parse_num(self):
        negative = False
        i = 0

        if self.rest[0] == '-':
            negative = True
            self.rest = self.rest[1:]

        while i < len(self.rest) and (self.rest[i].isdigit() or self.rest[i] == '.'):
            i += 1

        num = -float(self.rest[0:i]) if negative else float(self.rest[0:i])
        self.rest = self.rest[i:]

        return num

p = Parser()
print(p.parse("1+2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Не знаток питона, но разве при вызове метода класса не нужно ставить `this` or `self`?

Comment: я тоже не знаток, второй раз что либо пишу.. Скорее всего вы правы.

Comment: Тогда лучше начать с учебников и примеров, чем наобум писать.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Parser:
    acc = 0.0
    rest = ''

    def parse(self, s):
        self.acc = 0.0
        self.rest = s

        self.parse_plusminus() # Add self

        return self.acc

    def parse_plusminus(self):
        cur = self.parse_num() # Add self

        while len(self.rest) > 0:
            if not (self.rest[0] == '+' or self.rest[0] == '-'):
                break

            sign = self.rest[0]
            self.rest = self.rest[1:] # Remove first char? I guess so
            next_num = self.parse_num() # Add self

            if sign == '+':
                self.acc += cur + next_num
            else:
                self.acc += cur - next_num

    def parse_num(self):
        negative = False
        i = 0

        if self.rest[0] == '-':
            negative = True
            self.rest = self.rest[1:]

        while i < len(self.rest) and (self.rest[i].isdigit() or self.rest[i] == '.'):
            i += 1

        num = -float(self.rest[0:i]) if negative else float(self.rest[0:i])
        self.rest = self.rest[i:]

        return num

p = Parser()
print(p.parse("1+3")) # Output: 4.0
```